# Why action not found in my controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Save", "RequestFinishedDocument",
                                new {requestId = requestFinished.Request_ID, requestFinishedId = requestFinished.ID});
```

And in my controller I have:

```
public class RequestFinishedDocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(int requestId, int requestFinishedId)
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

But on the RedirectToAction call I get the exception message: 
**A public action method 'Save' was not found on controller 'SuiP.Controllers.RequestFinishedDocumentController'.**

What's wrong?

Thank

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`RedirectToAction` performs a HTTP GET. Your action method only accepts a HTTP POST.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing it to:

```
public class RequestFinishedDocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Save(int requestId, int requestFinishedId)
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

and see if that works.

Comment: Ah! I always get beat to it, haha.