# Why Action is not found on Controller exception occurs

Tags: asp.net-mvc

There is a situation like [in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511786/why-action-not-found-in-my-controller)

"...
I have this code:

```
return RedirectToAction("Save", "RequestFinishedDocument",
                                new {requestId = requestFinished.Request_ID, requestFinishedId = requestFinished.ID});
```

And in my controller I have:

```
public class RequestFinishedDocumentController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult Save(int requestId, int requestFinishedId)
    {
        //todo
    }
}
```

But on the RedirectToAction call I get the exception message: A public action method 'Save' was not found on controller 'SuiP.Controllers.RequestFinishedDocumentController'.

What's wrong?

Thanks..."

WHy asp.net mvc throws exception "Action is not found...." if action has **HttpPost** attribute instead of routing to catch all route that shows page not found.

Comment: I looked at the referenced question. How is the current answer different for your case? RedirectToAction is a get, therefore it cannot see a HttpPost attributed action of Save.

Answer (score 2):

Your redirecting to a post action, i presume from a get action method.

You can't redirect to a post method

Comment: No I don't. It's an url in the page path is used for Ajax post. Google bot comes and finds it and try to navigate to it.

Comment: @Jenea: If you are going to leave the link on the page then you should have a way to handle the HTTP GET. You can (1) leave it as-is and keep logging the error, (2) provide an [HttpGet] in addition to the [HttpPost] to handle the cases where the link is visited by users without JavaScript, or (3) remove the link from the page (and add it through JavaScript.)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are redirecting to a get method.

Your controller has a post method for the Save action but not a Get.

Comment: No I don't. It's an url in the page path is used for Ajax post. Google bot comes and finds it and try to navigate to it.

Comment: For what I can see in the code shown, RedirectToAction will redirect you to a get method, in your example is trying to redirect you to the httpGet Save method, as you haven't defined a httpGet Save method in your controller it throws an error.